# Error while pushing all *.gz files to aws s3 bucket - "bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `then'"

Tags: shell, amazon-s3

I am trying to push all *.gz files to aws s3 bucket but I getting this error bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

> ssh root@ "find /tmp/ -name "localhost_*.gz" -mtime -1 -exec s3cmd
>   put '{}' s3://script-testing/test1/  \; if [ $? == "0" ] ; then  echo
>   \"Successfully pushed the backup to s3 bucket\" | mail -s
>   \"Successfully pushed backup to S3 \" email-id; else echo \"Failed
>   pushing logs to S3 Bucket\" | mail -s \"Failed Pushing logs to s3\"
>   email-id; fi"

Comment: I checked syntax in http://www.shellcheck.net/. It looks all good. But I don't know where is the issue. Any help would be greatful.

Comment: That is one crazy question title. Consider moving the error message into your question. Good luck.

Comment: Note that unless there is an error with `find` itself, `$?` in your `if` statement will *always* be 0, whether or not there are any errors with any of the calls to `s3cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler (and clearer) to put your -exec command into a separate shell script - then you wouldn't have to escape the quotes etc, and you'd never have needed to ask this questions:

```
remote$ cat myscript.sh
s3cmd put "$1" s3://script-testing/test1/

if [ $? == "0" ] ; then
  ...


local$ ssh ... -exec myscript.sh '{}' \;
```

Notwithstanding that though:

1. Your double quotes aren't right, but that might be SO formatting or a cut/paste-ism, although:
2. Your entire command ought to be in single quotes rather than double quotes, although that would change your need for escaping.
3. Use single quotes for "localhost_*.gz" - otherwise bad things will happen if there happens to be a file matching that pattern in the current directory. You'll need to escape those quotes if you abide by step 2
4. You need to escape the semicolons within the -exec command (unless you put the whole lot into a script).
5. Strictly speaking, you ought to double-quote the $?, but don't need to quote the "0", but that won't cause any issues in this instance.

#3's the immediate cause of your problem though - the ; isn't escaped and so is taken literally, and bash then tries to run "then" as a shell command, which obviously fails.

If you really want to put the whole thing into one long command then I'd suggest getting it working as a separate shell script ("find ... -exec my-script.sh '{}' \;" where my-script.sh is your current -exec command), and then figure out what quoting/escaping is required to pass that script inline in the find command.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't terminate your find command, causing the error you see
2. Your `$?` expands on the client side
3. You neglect to escape some of your double quotes.

I suggest you start by creating a file with the script you want to execute on the remote side:

```
find /tmp/ -name 'localhost_*.gz' -mtime -1 -exec s3cmd put '{}' s3://script-testing/test1/ \;

if [ $? == 0 ]
then 
  echo "Successfully pushed the backup to s3 bucket" | mail -s "Successfully pushed backup to S3 "
else 
  echo "Failed pushing logs to S3 Bucket" | mail -s "Failed Pushing logs to s3" 
fi
```

Then you can either use the file directly:

```
ssh root@hostname "$(< yourfile)"
```

or let bash turn it into a literal argument that you can inline in your script:

```
printf "ssh root@host %q\n" "$(< yourfile)"
```

giving

```
ssh root@host $'find /tmp/ -name \'localhost_*.gz\' -mtime -1 -exec s3cmd put \'{}\' s3://script-testing/test1/ \\;\n\nif [ $? == 0 ]\nthen \n  echo "Successfully pushed the backup to s3 bucket" | mail -s "Successfully pushed backup to S3 "\nelse \n  echo "Failed pushing logs to S3 Bucket" | mail -s "Failed Pushing logs to s3"\nfi'
```

Answer (score 1):

`ssh` really isn't designed to embed complicated scripts in its single command argument. It's much better to save a script, copy that to the remote machine, and then execute *it* via `ssh`.

1. The exit status of `find` is independent of whether or not any call to `s3cmd` succeeds or fails. Your script should be something like

   ```
   # I'm assuming for simplicity that there is no whitespace in any of the
   # files that find will match.
   find /tmp/ -name "localhost_*.gz" -mtime -1 | while read fame; do
       if s3cmd put "$fname" s3://script-testing/test1/; then
           msg="Successfully pushed the backup $fname to s3 bucket"
       else
           msg="Failed pushing the backup $fname to s3 bucket"
       fi
       echo "$msg"
    done | mail -s "Results of pushing backups to s3 bucket" email-id
   ```

   This tests the result of running each instance of `s3cmd`, with a custom line
   for each file piped altogether to a single call to `mail`, so you get one e-mail
   summary. You can pipe to mail inside the loop if you really want one e-mail per file.
2. Copy your script to the remote host.

   ```
   scp script.sh host:
   ```
3. Now run the script via `ssh`

   ```
   ssh root@host bash script.sh
   ```